# Custom element class lookup not loading custom element

Tags: python, pytest, lxml

I am implementing tests for some `lxml` custom elements (e.g. `ParentElement`, `ChildElement`) which are registered via a decorator from a custom lookup class (`ModelLookup`).

`pytest` is used to run the tests and I am using fixtures defined in `conftest.py`.

The problem is that when the objects for the custom elements are created as part of a fixture the typing is lost on the test function and I get the following error:

```python
>   assert ['eclios', 'ruby'] == sorted([e.name for e in simple_tidy_family.child_element])
E   AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'name'
```

On the other hand, if the objects are created as part of the test function all runs fine.

Ideally, I would like to re-use these fixtures on other tests, hence having it defined in the conftest in the first place.

**Module code:**

```python
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from lxml import etree


class ModelLookup(etree.PythonElementClassLookup):

    _lookup = {}

    @classmethod
    def register_node_handler_class(cls, handler_cls):
        if handler_cls.cls_tag not in cls._lookup.keys():
            cls._lookup[handler_cls.cls_tag] = handler_cls
        return handler_cls

    def lookup(self, doc, node):
        if node.tag in self._lookup.keys():
            print(node.tag)
            return self._lookup[node.tag]
        return etree.ElementBase


@ModelLookup.register_node_handler_class
class ParentElement(etree.ElementBase):

    cls_tag = 'ParentElement'

    @staticmethod
    def tada():
        return 'tada'

    @property
    def child_element(self):
        return self.xpath('./ChildElement')

    @child_element.setter
    def child_element(self, value):
        self.append(value)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.get('name')

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.set('name', value)


@ModelLookup.register_node_handler_class
class ChildElement(etree.ElementBase):

    cls_tag = 'ChildElement'

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.get('name')

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.set('name', value)
```

**conftest.py**

```python
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import pytest
import xmlpal.xmlpal as xpal
import logging


@pytest.fixture()
def simple_family():

    ruby = xpal.ChildElement(**{'name': 'ruby'})
    eclios = xpal.ChildElement(**{'name': 'eclios'})

    adam = xpal.ParentElement()
    adam.append(ruby)
    adam.append(eclios)

    logging.info(f'my name is {ruby.name}')

    return adam
```

**test code:**

```python
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from lxml import etree
import xmlpal.xmlpal as xpal


def test_fixture_family(simple_family):

    assert 'tada' == simple_family.tada()
    assert isinstance(simple_family, xpal.ParentElement)
    assert 2 == len(simple_family.child_element)
    assert 2 == len([e for e in simple_family.child_element if isinstance(e, etree._Element)])
    assert ['eclios', 'ruby'] == sorted([e.name for e in simple_family.child_element])
    assert 2 == len([e for e in simple_family.child_element if isinstance(e, xpal.ChildElement)])


def test_local_family():

    ruby = xpal.ChildElement(**{'name': 'ruby'})
    eclios = xpal.ChildElement(**{'name': 'eclios'})

    adam = xpal.ParentElement()
    adam.append(ruby)
    adam.append(eclios)

    assert 'tada' == adam.tada()
    assert isinstance(adam, xpal.ParentElement)
    assert 2 == len(adam.child_element)
    assert 2 == len([e for e in adam.child_element if isinstance(e, etree._Element)])
    assert ['eclios', 'ruby'] == sorted([e.name for e in adam.child_element])
    assert 2 == len([e for e in adam.child_element if isinstance(e, xpal.ChildElement)])
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a custom lookup like that. A lookup is applied only when parsing the XML document tree from source. You are thus not invoking the custom lookup in your tests at all, never registering your custom element types. The rest of the issue you are experiencing is just the garbage collection between two function calls (yielding works because you are not exiting the scope of the fixture function). When the lookup is applied in parsing the document though, everything works as expected:

```
@pytest.fixture
def source():
    """Construct the tree and serialize it to string."""
    ruby = xpal.ChildElement(**{'name': 'ruby'})
    eclios = xpal.ChildElement(**{'name': 'eclios'})

    adam = xpal.ParentElement()
    adam.append(ruby)
    adam.append(eclios)

    return etree.tostring(adam)


@pytest.fixture
def tree(source):
    """Parse the tree from a string using a parser with custom lookup registered."""
    parser = etree.XMLParser()
    parser.set_element_class_lookup(xpal.ModelLookup())
    return etree.fromstring(source, parser)


def test_fixture_family(tree):
    adam = tree
    assert 'tada' == adam.tada()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I still find it a bit odd that the objects fall back to `_Element` when they are out of scope. Is there a recommended approach or any of the approaches are ok to use?

Comment: This is because `lxml` is not a pure-python library, it's core parts are written in C and its internal data representation is not a list of lists of elements as the interface might look like. In your case, the reference to the appended child elements will be dropped once you exit the function and collected by the GC. A new call to property `child_element` will cause a new `self.xpath` call, which will create new Python objects from internal data representation, so calling `adam.child_element` inside and outside the function will give you two different lists of different objects.

Comment: And because you didn't actually use your custom lookup, `lxml` doesn't know that `self.xpath('./ChildElement')` should return a `ChildElement` on the new `child_element` invocation - it doesn't even know such an element type exists! The actual lookup invocation, however, results in a different internal data representation, providing the info about custom python classes for elements, thus even though new invocations of `child_element` will still create new objects once the old are garbage collected, the information about your custom element type will be retained this time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem of pytest fixtures. The same error happens when `simple_family` is a normal function.

Woah, it looks like you have memory management problem :O. If you return all  objects from simple_family `return adam, eclios, ruby` or use `yield` everything works fine. If you don't use `yield`:

```
ruby is not simple_family.child_element[0]
```

Looks like some serious bug in the library.

EDIT: It also works fine if ruby and eclios are global variables :D

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's reassuring. I'll ping the `lxml` developers a message.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution but don't quite understand why it's working.

If I replace `return` with a `yield` in the fixture, all works as expected.

```python
@pytest.fixture()
def simple_tidy_family():

    ruby = xpal.ChildElement()
    ruby.name = 'ruby'
    eclios = xpal.ChildElement()
    eclios.name = 'eclios'

    adam = xpal.ParentElement()
    adam.append(ruby)
    adam.append(eclios)

    yield adam
```